# Comparing multiple field values together

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I compare multiple input field values and if there is a match alert 'There are similar values' using jQuery?

```
<input value="111"> //similar
<input value="222">
<input value="111"> //similar
<input value="333">
```

This html code above should alert 'There are similar values', as it has 2 values which are the same. How can it be done with jQuery?

My tried(Following code doesn't work):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/HpWLQ/

```
$('input').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var val = $this.val();
    vals.push(val);
});
for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
    for (var n = 0; n < vals.length; n++) {
        if (n !== i) {
            if (vals[i] === vals[n]) {
                alert('There are similar values');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf or http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/ instead of nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** In order to satisfy @Raynos, here's a pure JS solution.

```
var vals = {};
var flag = false;
var collection = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
collection = [].slice.call(collection);

collection.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    if (flag === true) return;
    var i = element.value;
    if (vals[i])
    {
        flag = true;
        alert('There are duplicates!');
    }
    else
    { 
        vals[i] = 1;
    }
});
```

​

---

*Bonus:* I ran my solutions through jsperf; the last one is [obviously by far the fastest](http://jsperf.com/discovering-duplicates).

**Edit:** Here's what would probably be *the jQuery way* of solving your problem **([Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pxp9n/3/))**. My original answer remains below.

```
var duplicatefound = false;
$('input').each(function(index, item){
    if (duplicatefound) return;
    val = $(item).val();
    if ($('input[value="' + val + '"]').length == 1) return;
    duplicatefound = true;
    alert('There are similar values');
});
```

​
Alternative solution in case you need to capture some or all of the duplicate values **([Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pxp9n/2/))**:

```
var collection = $('input');
var duplicates = $.map(collection, function(item){
    val = $(item).val();
    return ($('input[value="' + val + '"]').length > 1) ? val : null;
});

if(duplicates.length > 0) alert('There are similar values');
```

---

As others have mentioned, you were missing a declaration of `vals` as an array, therefore, `.push()` was failing.

You might find an object based solution to be more elegant: **[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/merua/)**

```
var vals = {};

$('input').each(function() {
    var index = $(this).val();
    if (vals[index])
    {
        vals[index]++
    }
    else
    { 
        vals[index] = 1;
    }
});

var duplicates = $.map(vals, function(val, key){
    return (val > 1) ? key : null;
});

if (duplicates.length > 0) alert('There are duplicates!');
```

Comment: The phrase "the fastest" in combination with jQuery is worth a downvote. The fastest solution is to always not use jQuery

Comment: @Raynos I stated quite clearly that I jsperf'd *my* solutions. Of those, #3 was the fastest. Of course, not using jQuery at all would be faster.

Comment: It's a tongue in cheek joke. The real downvote is for promoting code like `$('input[value="' + val + '"]')` which is horrible

Comment: @Raynos Oh, c'mon. Let's not get into pseudoreligious arguments about jQuery usage.

Comment: If you honestly don't think you deserve to be shot for using selectors with `value='" + lulz + '"` then you should probably learn what good code is

Comment: I am glad the downvote accusation was quickly retracted :P - I am curious by @Raynos point though. I wouldn't say it spawns from pseudoreligious hatred of jQuery in general, I just think not only are you string building selectors, you are trawling through the DOM to get those inputs each time? Maybe my understanding of the inner workings of jQuery is off, but it does feel a little ugly regardless.

Comment: your understanding of jQuery isn't wrong. It's ugly and wrong

Comment: The issue here is that we've not only created ugly code which is hard to read (or pass to someone else, like the people you want to answer a question), as well as maintain in a year, BUT we've also made a poor choice for how to locate things in the DOM. Unfortunately, we can't explain why this is terrible for working with the DOM in the comment boxes or on a Q&A site (I've tried, I nearly wrote a book in one answer, and it wasn't even complete). The best I can say is check out Mozilla Developer Network's guides on HTML/DOM/JS.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the `vals` to be an array. You can define it like

```
vals = [];
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/HpWLQ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
EDITED 2:    

function findDuplicates()
{
    var dupCount = 0;
    $('input').each(function () {
         var $currentInput = $(this);
         $('input').each(function () {
              if($(this).val() == $currentInput.val() && $(this) != $currentInput)
                   dupCount++;
         });
     });
     if(dupCount > 0) alert("There are " + dupCount + "duplicates!");
}
```

Comment: Try running this on a set with just one duplicate, not to mention multiple ones ;) http://jsfiddle.net/pxp9n/5/ There's plenty of alerts due to excessive iteration. You should set a flag if there was any duplicate and `return` early in the first `each` if that flag is `true`: http://jsfiddle.net/pxp9n/7/

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputs = $("input"), similar = [], i, j;

for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < inputs.length; j += 1) {
        if (inputs[i].value === inputs[j].value) {
            similar.push([i,j]);
        }
    }
}

if (similar.length > 0) {
    alert('There are similar values');
}​
```

Note that the this only compares unique permutations in order, and it gives you an array of matching indices in the similar array, in case this is interesting to you.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/sjCGy/

You could just as easily remove the jQuery dependency using document.getElementsByTagName instead of the jQuery selector.

And since @Raynos can't read, I'll make it explicit.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), similar = [], i, j;

for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < inputs.length; j += 1) {
        if (inputs[i].value === inputs[j].value) {
            similar.push([i,j]);
        }
    }
}

if (similar.length > 0) {
    alert('There are similar values');
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, you are just missing the declaration of the `vals` array - [See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HpWLQ/1/)

Comment: I don't mean to be holier than the pope, but a) you're iterating over each input, redeclaring `vals` to an empty array on every iteration b) you're checking for matches on every iteration, which is less than efficient.

Comment: @vzwick Yeah, you're right. Don't know what I was thinking with that one.